# Adjust table view

Tags: iphone

i am working on a project in which i have use Table view cell and iADBanner.when i am scrolling the table and want to see the last cell of table it goes behind the iAdbanner.How can i adjust the table so that i can see the last cell of the table along with iADbanner.

Comment: Adjust frame. Reduce height.. That should do it

Answer (score 3):

you have to set frame of your table and set its height to current height minus your iAd banner height.

```
[tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 410.0f)];
```

I assumed your iAd banner height is 50 and your table view origin from (0,0)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple , just need to set frame for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ads don't appear all the time, Your table View and iAd view should be inside a container view. So whenever there is an Ad to display:

```
 - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
   //Set the iAdview frame according to Orientation
   if(Want to show Ad)
    //Add the iAdView to the bottom of container View, pushing the table View up
   else
     //Remove iAd from Container View.
 }
```